# Add a checkbox to the dropdown list without any Javascript code or with Javascript code

Tags: html

How can I add a checkbox to the dropdown list below next to the options? If possible, please advise without using Java Codes.

```html
<div class="upload_modules">
  <div class="modules__title">
    <h4>Other Info</h4>
  </div>
  <!-- end /.module_title -->
  <div class="modules__content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="soft">vERSION</label>
          <div class="select-wrap select-wrap2">
            <select name="version" id="soft" class="text_field">
              <option value="">Select From List</option>
              <option value="4">WordPress 4</option>
              <option value="4.1">WordPress 4.1.*</option>
              <option value="4.2">WordPress 4.2.*</option>
              <option value="4.3">WordPress 4.3.*</option>
              <option value="4.4">WordPress 4.4.*</option>
            </select>
            <span class="lnr icon-arrow-down"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Java =/= javascript. You can't do it with native `<select>`, you'll need custom html dropdown. There are plenty of tutorials for that. But it won't be possible use it in forms without javascript.

Comment: if you can give me some solution @vanowm with javascript. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching on internet websites that had tutorials about CSS and HTML, I managed to find a code and use it. The code is as follows:

```js
const MultiSelectDropdown = (params) => {
        let config = {
            search: true,
            hideX: false,
            useStyles: true,
            placeholder: 'Select...',
            txtSelected: 'Selected',
            txtAll: 'All',
            txtRemove: 'Remove',
            txtSearch: 'Search...',
            minWidth: '160px',
            maxWidth: '360px',
            maxHeight: '180px',
            borderRadius: 6,
            ...params
        };

        const newElement = (tag, params) => {
            let element = document.createElement(tag);
            if (params) {
                Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
                    if (key === 'class') {
                        Array.isArray(params[key])
                            ? params[key].forEach((o) => (o !== '' ? element.classList.add(o) : 0))
                            : params[key] !== ''
                                ? element.classList.add(params[key])
                                : 0;
                    } else if (key === 'style') {
                        Object.keys(params[key]).forEach((value) => {
                            element.style[value] = params[key][value];
                        });
                    } else if (key === 'text') {
                        params[key] === '' ? (element.innerHTML = '&nbsp;') : (element.innerText = params[key]);
                    } else {
                        element[key] = params[key];
                    }
                });
            }
            return element;
        };

        document.querySelectorAll('select[multiple]').forEach((multiSelect) => {
            let div = newElement('div', { class: 'multiselect-dropdown' });
            multiSelect.style.display = 'none';
            multiSelect.parentNode.insertBefore(div, multiSelect.nextSibling);
            let dropdownListWrapper = newElement('div', { class: 'multiselect-dropdown-list-wrapper' });
            let dropdownList = newElement('div', { class: 'multiselect-dropdown-list' });
            let search = newElement('input', {
                class: ['multiselect-dropdown-search'].concat([config.searchInput?.class ?? 'form-control']),
                style: {
                    width: '100%',
                    display: config.search ? 'block' : multiSelect.attributes.search?.value === 'true' ? 'block' : 'none'
                },
                placeholder: config.txtSearch
            });
            dropdownListWrapper.appendChild(search);
            div.appendChild(dropdownListWrapper);
            dropdownListWrapper.appendChild(dropdownList);

            multiSelect.loadOptions = () => {
                dropdownList.innerHTML = '';

                if (config.selectAll || multiSelect.attributes['select-all']?.value === 'true') {
                    let optionElementAll = newElement('div', { class: 'multiselect-dropdown-all-selector' });
                    let optionCheckbox = newElement('input', { type: 'checkbox' });
                    optionElementAll.appendChild(optionCheckbox);
                    optionElementAll.appendChild(newElement('label', { text: config.txtAll }));

                    optionElementAll.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        optionElementAll.classList.toggle('checked');
                        optionElementAll.querySelector('input').checked = !optionElementAll.querySelector('input').checked;

                        let ch = optionElementAll.querySelector('input').checked;
                        dropdownList.querySelectorAll(':scope > div:not(.multiselect-dropdown-all-selector)').forEach((i) => {
                            if (i.style.display !== 'none') {
                                i.querySelector('input').checked = ch;
                                i.optEl.selected = ch;
                            }
                        });

                        multiSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
                    });
                    optionCheckbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        optionCheckbox.checked = !optionCheckbox.checked;
                    });

                    dropdownList.appendChild(optionElementAll);
                }

                Array.from(multiSelect.options).map((option) => {
                    let optionElement = newElement('div', { class: option.selected ? 'checked' : '', srcElement: option });
                    let optionCheckbox = newElement('input', { type: 'checkbox', checked: option.selected });
                    optionElement.appendChild(optionCheckbox);
                    optionElement.appendChild(newElement('label', { text: option.text }));

                    optionElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        optionElement.classList.toggle('checked');
                        optionElement.querySelector('input').checked = !optionElement.querySelector('input').checked;
                        optionElement.srcElement.selected = !optionElement.srcElement.selected;
                        multiSelect.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
                    });
                    optionCheckbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        optionCheckbox.checked = !optionCheckbox.checked;
                    });
                    option.optionElement = optionElement;
                    dropdownList.appendChild(optionElement);
                });
                div.dropdownListWrapper = dropdownListWrapper;

                div.refresh = () => {
                    // For demo purposes, remove
                    let tempSelectedList = document.getElementById('dropdownSelected');

                    div.querySelectorAll('span.optext, span.placeholder').forEach((placeholder) => div.removeChild(placeholder));
                    let selected = Array.from(multiSelect.selectedOptions);
                    if (selected.length > (multiSelect.attributes['max-items']?.value ?? 5)) {
                        div.appendChild(
                            newElement('span', {
                                class: ['optext', 'maxselected'],
                                text: selected.length + ' ' + config.txtSelected
                            })
                        );
                        // For demo purposes, remove
                        tempSelectedList
                            .querySelectorAll('span')
                            .forEach((span, index) => index !== 0 && tempSelectedList.removeChild(span));
                        selected.map((option) => tempSelectedList.appendChild(newElement('span', { text: option.text })));
                    } else {
                        // For demo purposes, remove
                        tempSelectedList
                            .querySelectorAll('span')
                            .forEach((span, index) => index !== 0 && tempSelectedList.removeChild(span));

                        selected.map((option) => {
                            let span = newElement('span', {
                                class: 'optext',
                                text: option.text,
                                srcElement: option
                            });
                            if (!config.hideX) {
                                span.appendChild(
                                    newElement('span', {
                                        class: 'optdel',
                                        text: '',
                                        title: config.txtRemove,
                                        onclick: (e) => {
                                            span.srcElement.optionElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
                                            div.refresh();
                                            e.stopPropagation();
                                        }
                                    })
                                );
                            }
                            div.appendChild(span);
                            // For demo purposes, remove
                            tempSelectedList.appendChild(newElement('span', { text: option.text }));
                        });
                    }
                    if (multiSelect.selectedOptions?.length === 0) {
                        div.appendChild(
                            newElement('span', {
                                class: 'placeholder',
                                text: multiSelect.attributes?.placeholder?.value ?? config.placeholder
                            })
                        );
                        // For demo purposes, remove
                        tempSelectedList.appendChild(newElement('span', { text: 'n/a' }));
                    }
                };
                div.refresh();
            };
            multiSelect.loadOptions();

            search.addEventListener('input', () => {
                dropdownList.querySelectorAll(':scope div:not(.multiselect-dropdown-all-selector)').forEach((div) => {
                    let innerText = div.querySelector('label').innerText.toLowerCase();
                    div.style.display = innerText.includes(search.value.toLowerCase()) ? 'flex' : 'none';
                });
            });

            div.addEventListener('click', () => {
                div.dropdownListWrapper.style.display = 'block';
                search.focus();
                search.select();
            });

            document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                if (!div.contains(e.target)) {
                    dropdownListWrapper.style.display = 'none';
                    div.refresh();
                }
            });
        });

        const createStyles = () => {
            let styles = {
                ':root': {
                    '--color-background': '#ffffff',
                    '--color-border': '#ced4da',
                    '--color-background--option': '#d6dde6',
                    '--color-background--option--hover': '#cbd5e0a1',
                    '--color-text--normal': '#0c0c0c',
                    '--color-text--grey': '#24262c',
                    '--color-text--red': '#cc6666',
                    '--color-text--placeholder': '#ced4da',
                    '--border-radius--base': `${parseInt(config.borderRadius)}px` || '6px',
                    '--border-radius--small': `${parseInt(config.borderRadius) * 0.75}px` || '4px'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown': {
                    position: 'relative',
                    display: 'inline-flex',
                    'flex-wrap': 'wrap',
                    padding: '6px 36px 6px 6px',
                    gap: '6px',
                    'border-radius': 'var(--border-radius--base)',
                    border: 'solid 1px var(--color-border)',
                    background: 'var(--color-background)',
                    'background-image':
                        "url(\"data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23343a40' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='M2 5l6 6 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e\")",
                    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                    'background-position': 'right 6px center',
                    'background-size': '16px 12px',
                    'min-width': `${config.minWidth}` ?? '140px',
                    'max-width': `${config.maxWidth}` ?? '360px',
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                'span.optext, span.placeholder': {
                    display: 'inline-flex',
                    'justify-content': 'center',
                    'align-items': 'center',
                    'font-size': '16px',
                    'border-radius': 'var(--border-radius--small)'
                },
                'span.optext': {
                    'background-color': 'var(--color-background--option)',
                    padding: '0 12px 2px 6px',
                    cursor: 'default',
                    '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
                    '-moz-user-select': 'none',
                    '-ms-user-select': 'none',
                    'user-select': 'none'
                },
                'span.optext .optdel': {
                    float: 'right',
                    margin: '0 -6px 1px 6px',
                    'font-size': '12px',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    color: 'var(--color-text--grey)'
                },
                'span.optext .optdel:hover': {
                    color: 'var(--color-text--red)'
                },
                'span.placeholder': {
                    color: 'var(--color-border)'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list-wrapper': {
                    'z-index': 100,
                    'border-radius': 'var(--border-radius--base)',
                    border: 'solid 1px var(--color-border)',
                    display: 'none',
                    margin: '-1px',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    background: 'var(--color-background)'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-search': {
                    padding: '5px 6px 6px 5px',
                    'border-top-left-radius': 'var(--border-radius--base)',
                    'border-top-right-radius': 'var(--border-radius--base)',
                    border: 'solid 1px transparent',
                    'border-bottom': 'solid 1px var(--color-border)',
                    'font-size': 'inherit'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-search::placeholder': {
                    color: 'var(--color-text--placeholder)',
                    'font-size': '16px'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-search:focus, .multiselect-dropdown-search:focus-visible': {
                    outline: 'none'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list': {
                    'overflow-y': 'auto',
                    'overflow-x': 'hidden',
                    height: '100%',
                    'max-height': `${config.maxHeight}` ?? '160px'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list::-webkit-scrollbar': {
                    width: '4px'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
                    'background-color': 'var(--color-background--option)',
                    'border-radius': '1000px'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list div, .multiselect-dropdown-list div > input, .multiselect-dropdown-list div > label':
                {
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    'border-radius': 'var(--border-radius--base)'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list div': {
                    display: 'flex',
                    'align-items': 'center',
                    'justify-content': 'flex-start',
                    'column-gap': '6px',
                    padding: '6px',
                    margin: '6px 4px',
                    transition: '100ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955)'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list div:hover': {
                    'background-color': 'var(--color-background--option--hover)'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-list-input': {
                    height: '14px',
                    width: '14px',
                    border: 'solid 1px var(--color-text--grey)',
                    margin: 0
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown span.maxselected': {
                    width: '100%'
                },
                '.multiselect-dropdown-all-selector': {
                    'border-bottom': 'solid 1px var(--color-border)'
                }
            };
            const style = document.createElement('style');
            style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
            style.innerHTML = `${Object.keys(styles)
                .map(
                    (selector) =>
                        `${selector} { ${Object.keys(styles[selector])
                            .map((property) => `${property}: ${styles[selector][property]}`)
                            .join('; ')} }`
                )
                .join('\n')}`;
            document.head.appendChild(style);
        };

        config.useStyles && createStyles();
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        MultiSelectDropdown(window.MultiSelectDropdownOptions);
    });
```

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html, body, div {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: #fafafa;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        body, div, span, input, select, p {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }

        form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            gap: 14px;
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        body > .wrapper {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .container {
            width: 50%;
            max-width: 420px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            margin-top: 14px;
        }

        body > .wrapper > .container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: unset;
            margin-bottom: 80px;
        }

        #dropdownSelected > span:first-of-type {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Multiselect Dropdown Demo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container" id="dropdownSelected">
        <span>Selected</span>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <select 
          multiple
          search='true'
        >
          <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
          <option value="Portland">Portland</option>
          <option value="Halifax">Halifax</option>
          <option value="London">London</option>
          <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
          <option value="Toronto">Toronto</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```